# What's the advantage of storing a newid() in a column with datatype UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2012 table has the following column definition:

```
[GlobalId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NULL,
```

Is there any advantage in this being defined as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER or could I just define it
as a string. The reason I ask is because at a later time I might want to not store the full
value of the GUID and I might want to generate my own Id.

Now it's stored as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER can I change the definition to a string
and still have the DEFAULT work?

Here's an example of what I have stored in the GlobalId column:

```
6ffcac5e-88f1-4207-bbbe-0fc14265c01f
```

Comment: [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is a 16-byte binary value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx) NOT a string so storage memory usage is lower and an index size is smaller too. Also in this case you avoid conversion of NEWID() result to a STRING.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to change this to a string how can I do this? How could I convert newid() to give a string. You mention it's a 16 bit binary value but then when I look at it I see values like this: 6ffcac5e-88f1-4207-bbbe-0fc14265c01f

Comment: 2 things come to mind.  1.  Replication scenarios become easier to manage.  2.  You can create relationships OUTSIDE of the database, aka, you don't have to wait for the sql server to create the @@IDENTITY values and then insert (children) records.  You can create all these relationships outside of the database, and then just jam them in.  There are cons to this approach, but that's one of the main advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the link provided by valex,

> A GUID is a unique binary number; no other computer in the world will
>   generate a duplicate of that GUID value. The main use for a GUID is
>   for assigning an identifier that must be unique in a network that has
>   many computers at many sites.

So the interest is this famous unique fact.

If you want string values, use string values, but the built-in functions in sql server allowing the generation of new values is NEWID and NEWSEQUENTIALID, which gives UNIQUEIDENTIFIERs.

You are not obliged to use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for identity columns, it will depend on your datamodel and servers: if only one database server generates the keys, a sequence ID is fine, and is somewhat more efficient (and a heck of a lot easier to read) than a GUID. Iif multiple servers generate the keys then go with a GUID

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the question you are asking. But one seems to be how to convert a uniqueidentifer to a string.
 To convert a uniqueidenitifier to a string 
convert(char(36), newid()) will return a string.